# GKSession on iOS 6.0 cannot 'see' session on iOS5.1

Tags: ios5, ios6, wifi, game-center, gksession

Just noticed some strange behaviour testing GKsession on devices running iOS6 and iOS5.1  It seems that a GKSession on a local wireless network using the same session ID in sessionMode:GKSessionModePeer works fine from 6.0 to 5.1 but not the other way round.  i.e a session created on 6.0 is 'seen' by 5.1 but not the other way around.

```
self.theGame.hostListSession = [[GKSession alloc] initWithSessionID:@"FRED" 
                                                      displayName:[KYTConfig sharedInstance].localPlayerAlias
                                                      sessionMode:GKSessionModePeer];
[self.theGame.hostListSession setDelegate:self];  
[self.theGame.hostListSession setDataReceiveHandler:self withContext:nil];
[self.theGame.hostListSession setAvailable:YES];
```

Anyone else experience this or know of any workaround?

Comment: I did some tests and is working normally here: iPad 1 5.1 as server connected to an iPhone 4s 6.0.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to saulobrito for confirming that it works okay for you.  This prompted me to do a clean and build and reinstall the game center framework and the problem disappeared.